# Overwriting NAMESPACE and Rd with roxygen2

Tags: r, rstudio, roxygen2

I create a new package with RStudio. In "Configure Build Tools", I check "Generate documentation with Roxygen".

The first time I click on "Document" in the "Build" pane, everything works fine:

```
==> roxygen2::roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
Writing hello.Rd
Writing NAMESPACE
Documentation completed
```

I get this NAMESPACE:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(hello)
```

and this file `hello.Rd`:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/hello.R
\name{hello}
\alias{hello}
\title{Hello}
\usage{
hello(x)
}
\arguments{
\item{x}{string}
}
\value{
a string
}
```

But now, I modify the file `hello.R`, and then I get two problems. 
Firstly, this window appears:

[image]

If I click on "Yes", nothing happens.

Secondly, it seems that `roxygen2` cannot overwrite `hello.Rd`, because I get this text in the "Build" pane:

```
==> roxygen2::roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Error: The specified file is not readable: U:\Data\Rtests\testPackage\man/hello.Rd
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

The only way I found to update the documentation is to run:

```
roxygen2::roxygenize(clean=TRUE)
```

This command firstly cleans everything, the NAMESPACE and the `Rd` files, and then generates the NAMESPACE and the `Rd` files.

I don't know whether this is an issue with the path of `Rtools`. I tried to set the path by doing:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH="%PATH%;C:/Program Files/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin;C:/Program Files/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin64;C:/Program Files/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/i686-w64-mingw32/bin;C:/Program Files/Rtools/bin")
```

But that does not solve the issue.

I'm using:

- `roxygen2 5.0.1`
- RStudio 0.99.892
- Windows 7
- `R version 3.3.1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Cause of the problem.

The `roxygen2` package depends on the `digest` package. The error (*The specified file is not readable*) is generated by the `digest` function of the `digest` package, at the moment when this function calls the `file.access` function: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/blob/master/R/digest.R#L102.

I get:

```
> file.access("U:/Data", 4)
U:/Data 
     -1
```

That means that `U:/Data` has not the read permission. But this is not true: it has the read permission. The problem is that my `U:` drive is a "network drive", and there are some issues with the `file.access` function for network drives, as we can see here for example: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/issues/13.

### A workaround

The problem would be solved if `R.utils::fileAccess` would be used instead of `file.access` in the `digest::digest` function.

So, firstly take the code of the `digest::digest` function and modify it as follows.

```
mydigest <- function (object, algo = c("md5", "sha1", "crc32", "sha256", 
    "sha512", "xxhash32", "xxhash64", "murmur32"), serialize = TRUE, 
    file = FALSE, length = Inf, skip = "auto", ascii = FALSE, 
    raw = FALSE, seed = 0, errormode = c("stop", "warn", "silent")) 
{
  file.access <- R.utils::fileAccess
  .... the code of the digest function here ...
}
```

Then do:

```
library(digest)
R.utils::reassignInPackage("digest", "digest", mydigest)
```

And now the documentation can be updated by doing:

```
roxygen2::roxygenize()
```

Comment: But as that very issue ticket discussion tries to explain, this is digest calling R and R calling system functions -- so ultimately a _Windows_ setup issue.  Hence no simply fix.  Maybe change the working directory.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Of course I could change the working directory... but actually no, I can't: this is the computer I use for my job, and this is the folder for which the company does a backup, that's why I use this folder. I've proposed a possible solution on [the digest Github repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/issues/49), but the author disagrees.

Comment: Think about it a little harder: it is really just like I suggested in that that GH thread you reference:  write a simple script that copies from the (borked) network drive to `c:\`, process there, remove.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Oh! I've just realized you are the author of the digest package, who replied on Github... Thank you again, I will study your recommendations later.