# How to add an infix function to a package?

Tags: r, package, documentation, infix-notation

I want to add a infix function to a package but the `%%`s challenge me.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24768545/6574038) but unfortunately it doesn't explain where exactly the line `export("%IN%")` should be added. I didn't get any smarter from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24768773/6574038) question either. Since the questions are five years old I decided to ask a new question.

Consider the same function as in the first linked question.

```
"%IN%" <- function(x, table) x & match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

I usually add a new function to my package writing a `<myfun>_function.R` file according to this rough template.

```
#' Title
#'
#' \code{%IN%} does this and that
#' @param x texttext    
#' @param table texttext
#' @return texttext
#' @export
#' @examples
#' 1:5 %IN% 1:3
"%IN%" <- function(x, table) x & match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

Accordingly I'd save a file named `` "`%IN%`_function.R" `` to the `R` folder of my package directory `X`.

Then in `setwd("./X")` I run these lines of code

```
library(digest)
R.utils::reassignInPackage("digest", "digest", mydigest)
roxygen2::roxygenize()
```

(Where I got `mydigest` from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40550843/6574038)).

At the end in the terminal I create the package with `R CMD build X`.

**So, where exactly is the `export("%IN%")` line to be added?**

Comment: the name of your file doesn't matter, though I would choose a less weird one, like `infix_ops.R`, but you need to add `@export`, as you should for other functions that you want to export.

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/moodymudskipper/mmassign/blob/master/R/more_ops.R and here : https://github.com/moodymudskipper/mmassign/blob/master/NAMESPACE

Comment: "where exactly is the export("%IN%") line to be added?" In your package's NAMESPACE file. (The same as for all other functions you want to export.)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for your clues and your examples, I made it work!

Comment: @Roland Thx, got it and summarized it in an own answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments the trick is to do in this order:

1. write the function's `*.R` file as usual, name it arbitrary
2. run `roxygenize()`
3. in package folder edit the generated `NAMESPACE` file by adding a line `export("%IN%")` with great delight by hand
4. run `R CMD build <package name>` in terminal
5. perhaps update version number
6. install

Comment: You do not need to edit the file by hand if you use the `@export` directive with roxygen2: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html

Comment: @Roland Could you be more specific how this relates to my problem?

Comment: Per your answer you are using roxygen2. You are not using its full potential if you don't use it to create/edit your NAMESPACE file. I don't edit my NAMESPACE files by hand and still export functions.